# MySQL batch-file call flush tables for export

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I use batch-file for copy database from server1 to server2.

```
Step 1: call stored procedure for FLUSH TABLES table1,table2, ..., table1000 FOR EXPORT;
Step 2: copy files .ibd and .cfg to temp directory and archive this
Step 3: unlock tables;
```

The problem is the first step - files .cfg are created and then removed, but unlock the tables is not called. Why? Files .cfg are created and immediately disappear, I do not have time to copy

.bat file command:

```
mysql -u %db_user% -p%db_password% %db_name% --default-character-set=utf8 < stored_proc_flush_tables.sql
```

file stored_proc_flush_tables.sql:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  stored_proc_flush_tables;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE stored_proc_flush_tables
(   

)
BEGIN

DECLARE t_name BLOB;
DECLARE tmp_query BLOB;
DECLARE done_tables INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE cursor_tables CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema=DB_NAME;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done_tables = 1;

SET @table_name = '';
SET @tmp_query = '';

OPEN cursor_tables;

    tables_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cursor_tables INTO t_name;
        IF done_tables = 1 THEN
            LEAVE tables_loop;
        END IF;

        SET @tmp_query = CONCAT_WS('', @tmp_query, ',', t_name);

    END LOOP;
CLOSE cursor_tables;

SET @tmp_query = TRIM(LEADING ',' FROM @tmp_query);
SET @tmp_query = CONCAT_WS('', 'FLUSH TABLES', ' ', @tmp_query, ' ', 'FOR EXPORT');
PREPARE stmt FROM @tmp_query;
EXECUTE stmt;

END //
DELIMITER ;

call stored_proc_flush_tables();
```

Files .cfg are created and immediately disappear, I do not have time to copy them

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you end mysql session that makes **FLUSH TABLES ... FOR EXPORT**
before you try to copy files.

When mysql session/connection ends all locks unlocked and *.cfg is consired as temporal file is deleted.

So you should have program that makes FLUSH ... FOR EXPORT and keeps session
open and then copies files and after that releases table lock (or ends session).